# Cannot access internal property 'ConvertedHtmlElementSelector' here

Tags: c#, hiqpdf

I am using HiQPdf Free to generate PDFs from an URL. I noticed in [their documentation](http://www.hiqpdf.com/documentation/convert-html-part.aspx), you can simply grab a specific element instead of the whole page. It would go something like this:

```
HtmlToPdf htmlToPdfConverter = new HtmlToPdf();

htmlToPdfConverter.ConvertedHtmlElementSelector = "#logo";

htmToPdfConverter.ConvertUrlToFile("https://your-website.com/", "/path/to/pdf.pdf");
```

However, when I do the `htmlToPdfConverter.ConvertedHtmlElementSelector` in my code, it tells me this error:

> Cannot access internal property 'ConvertedHtmlElementSelector' here

Could this be because it's a paid only feature? That seems like the only obvious reason, however, I haven't been able to find any source on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting only a region of the HTML page to PDF is a feature of the full version and it is not available in the free version. There is an example for this feature with C# and VB.NET code samples at http://www.hiqpdf.com/demo/ConvertHtmlRegionToPdf.aspx

Comment: Yeah I figured that. It would be nice to have that in the free version, or at least mentioned somewhere that this is premium only.